# Should single men not sit at corner of the table?

Tags: sources-mekorot, marriage, men-male, segulah

I heard that there some say that single men should not sit at the corner of the table, because it could lead to someone staying single forever. Is there a source for this idea?

Comment: sounds very superstitious

Comment: @armoose This belief exists in my circles, although with women and fertility. I would not be surprised if the source of this and many others is Russia, where very similar superstitions are alive and well today

Answer (score 3):

Poking around on the Internet I couldn't find any references to this particular adage. But the concept is simple enough, I think, that its source can be inferred. Historically, parents (mothers in particular) want their children to find love and to marry well. Just like at little league sports events, they watch from the stands and develop a neurotic interest in the success of their children in this pursuit. And they notice minor things, like the fact that boys and men positioned in the middle of a long rectangular table have greater access to the attention of the girls and women at the table.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Adam, and thanks for the answer. Just to clarify: this is your own idea?

Comment: Thanks, @Scimonster. Yep. It's pure inference based on observation and experience.

Comment: This is what the idea sounds like to me, as well.  "Bubbe, just get in the middle and meet a nice meidl already!  None of this hanging on the corners business."